# Is it possible to have a contract run whenever a wallet address receives a transaction?

Tags: contract-design, contract-invocation

I'd like to build some code that monitors a wallet address, and performs an action whenever that wallet receives a transaction.

I could do this with say javascript or whatever, but that doesn't offer any guarantees to people that I will actually run it. Hence my desire to look into smart contracts or the like for this, where a contract is published to the blockchain and people can verify that it will run, so when they submit their transaction to the wallet address, the expectated behaviour will occur.

Comment: No. You'll need to monitor the address from an off-chain script, and invoke your contract function whenever it receives a transaction. Alternatively, you can implement a `payable` function in your contract, which takes this address as a parameter, and then do whatever it is you want to do. So you'll get the desired behavior, but only when people choose to transfer funds via your designated `payable` function. If they do it in the "standard" way, then your contract will have no knowledge about it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Do you know if there are any ethereum alternatives that encode such behaviour? I guess assigning an immutable contract to a wallet upon its creation, that persists for its lifetime.

Comment: No. The Ethereum block-chain is "passive" by nature. You cannot get it to "automatically run" in response to something. Every operation is initiated explicitly (by miners).

Answer (score 0):

To add to goodvibration's answer, I'm not what you're trying to achieve exactly, but you can trigger code with a `fallback` function - as in a user will just send eth, and the code will execute, without having to manually call any functions - but you have to set that up, you don't add that to a pre-existing address. But you can definitely create a wallet that, upon installation/initiation, creates a personal version of a contract that includes a fallback function (however they will need some eth to initiate this because creating the contract every time requires gas).